# Save Picture in `askedfilename` function to local in tkinter python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, save

My Intention is to create an application write(entry label) on the Image I imported to tkinter and export with 'asksaveasfilename' to ask the user what format they want to save as.

I had tried
'image.save()'

```
#!/use/bin/env python3
import os
import tkinter
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from PIL import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("520x800")
window.title("STARLABS BIOSCIENCE SDN BHD")
window.resizable(False, False)
window.config(background="#150051")

MENUBAR = Menu(window)
window.config(menu=MENUBAR)

image = Image.open("s.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = Label(window, image=photo, text="").pack()
venuelabel = Label(window, text="Venue: ", background="#150051", font=("bold", 13,)).place(x=0, y=660)
contactLabel = Label(window, text="Contact: ").place(x=0, y=720)
dateTEXT = Entry(window, width=35, ).place(x=170, y=380)
Venue = ScrolledText(window, width=35, background="#150051").place(x=57, y=660, height=60)
person = Entry(window, width=35).place(x=57, y=720)


# function :
def exitWindow():
    window.destroy()


def save():
    print("save")
    dialogue = image.filename = asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(
        ('JPEG', ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.jpe')), ('PNG', '*.png'), ('BMP', ('*.bmp', '*.jdib')), ('GIF', '*.gif')))
    image.save("picture.jpg")


# Add Menu Items:
file_menu = Menu(MENUBAR, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_cascade(label="Save", command=save)
addon = Menu(file_menu, tearoff=0)
addon.add_command(label="SAVE TO FILE")
addon.add_command(label="Email To")
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exitWindow)
MENUBAR.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)

window.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've showed us what you've tried, but didn't explain why the code isn't good enough. What's wrong with what you've tried? Does it save the wrong image? Does it save the right image to the wrong place? Does it throw an error? If it throws an error, what's the error?

Comment: Thanks man, Mr Henry just helped me. Problem solved. Now I am figuring out how to close this case.

Answer (score 1):

`Image.save` is correct, but you need to `ImageGrab` the screen and crop the image first. Right now you are just saving the image you opened.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Entry(root).pack()

def save_pic():
    result = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(
        ('JPEG', ('*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.jpe')), ('PNG', '*.png'), ('BMP', ('*.bmp', '*.jdib')), ('GIF', '*.gif')))
    if result:
        x = root.winfo_rootx()
        y = root.winfo_rooty()
        height = root.winfo_height() + y
        width = root.winfo_width() + x
        ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, width, height)).save(result)

tk.Button(root,text="Click me",command=save_pic).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried your method :: Am I doing it right?
https://gist.github.com/johnmelodyme/c8184ed4aa8754ab2f8227f5ecdb1610

Comment: In your `save` function, it should be `result=asksaveasfilename(...)`. Or just rename to whatever you like.

Comment: I sorry, I tried , I forgot to update you. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johnm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/WEBAPPLICATION/autoeditshit/StarLabs.py", line 42, in save
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, width, height)).save(result)
  File "C:\Users\johnm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2070, in save
    raise ValueError("unknown file extension: {}".format(ext))
ValueError: unknown file extension:

Comment: You need to input your file extension when you save the file, i.e. type `abc.jpg` during the file dialog.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you , you indeed saved mylife .

Comment: If it helped, consider accepting the answer so the question can be closed.